# Ableton Mastering: Is It Recommended That I Use Maximizers/Limiters Before Everything Else?

Tags: ableton-live, mastering, production

I recently asked a question regarding increasing the loudness of my mix, and after receiving a lot of helpul tips + knowledge, I am now curious as to wether or not I should be using my Maximizers/Limiters first, and then the rest of the mastering apects on top of it?

Any help or guidance with this is much appreciated, Thankyou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that doesn't make much sense. The point of a maximiser/limiter is to exploit the 0dBFS range as thoroughly as possible, but 0dBFS is only a meaningful range at the very end of the mastering process: it's the highest level that can be expressed by the consumer format you're exporting to. OTOH, digital plugins use floating-point arithmetic internally, which reaches to the absurd level of +1848 dBFS. Of course, that doesn't mean you should drive them so loud – for standard digital EQs it simply doesn't matter, and nonlinear / analogue plugins will sound differently depending on the input level, so you should drive them with a reasonable level that *sounds good*, likely something around -3 dBFS.

If you use a maximiser as simply an extreme compressor in front of another FX, the result will in general *not* be "maximised" any more. In particular, applying an EQ to a hard-maximised bass drum hit (the transients of which are effectively clipped by a limiter) [will normally increase the level to something like +2 dBFS](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/30221/why-signal-is-overloaded-when-i-use-a-low-cut-filter/30232#30232). So to get the result out for consumer, you will then need *another* limiter. Which would really harm the signal more than necessesary.

So: put the limiter at the very end of the chain. A reasonable setup might look something like `softComp -> EQ -> tapeSaturation -> multibandComp -> maximiser/limiter`.

Comment: Ahhhh I see, so the maximizer/limiter is to be used once I am completely happy with the rest of my mastering... @leftaroundabout

Comment: Once you're completely happy with the rest, precisely. IMO [the limiter should not audibly change the signal at all](http://prorec.com/2013/05/over-the-limit-the-loudness-war/), just safe-guard against digital clipping.

Comment: But wouldn't the limiter's role in increasing the loudness natturally affect the signal anyways? Is that not why people master at -6db sometimes? so they can use the mastering to bring it up to 0db? @leftaroundabout

Comment: @DannyJones: I've never heard about somebody _mastering_ at -6dB, you probably mean they _mix_ at -6dB. Sure, bringing up the level in mastering is fine and quite necessary to sound decent, but it shouldn't be done with a brickwall limiter IMO – multiple soft compressors and analogue saturation can do almost the same while preserving much more of the dynamic content. Only problem: you will typically end up with a few freak transients above 0 dBFS. If you then use a digital limiter to shave these off, it shouldn't sound notably different at all, but still stay in the permitted range.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Would you recommend Izotope Ozone 5's Maximizer tool to do increase loudness at all? @leftaroundabout

Comment: Yes. A well-designed maximiser (and iZotope plugins are pretty great design) does more than just brickwall limiting, it's effectively an integral combination of the effects I mentioned.

Comment: You've been very helpful, much appreciated! @leftaroundabout

Answer (score 1):

Limiting should not be audible, imo. If you are manipulating something like a multiband limiter ( Like the waves [L3 multimaximizer](http://www.waves.com/plugins/l3-multimaximizer#introduction-to-the-l3-and-l3-ll-multimaximizers)) to get pleasing results. You would get MORE pleasing results isolating the offending channels that make up that band and compressing/ eqing there.

Usually when Mastering, the limiter would be last. Not change the sonic characteristics of the audio, besides a linear gain increase. And most importantly, protect the analog equipment from overloading.